# Abstract methods like in Java

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem. You see, I want to do the same as this Java code:

```
new Runnable() {

//run() is a method that you need to
//implement when you create any
//new instance of Runnable
public void run() {
//Code goes here
}
}
```

where Java has you implement abstract methods like with a Runnable. The thing is, I am trying to replicate the same thing in Python by passing an argument in the init method of a class and then store that method as a variable  in the class (self.method)
where I run that method at some point later in the code of that class. The thing is, all the arguments of the method have to be passed when the class is created, not when the method is called, which is when I want to pass the arguments:

```
class AbstractExample():

    def __init__(self, method):
        method #Run method

def exampleMethod(arg1,arg2):
    print str(arg1) + "," + str(arg2)

AbstractExample(exampleMethod(5,7))
```

The output is: "5,7" and if I don't pass arguments when the class is created like above, I get an error. My question is, is there any way that I can do the Java code above in another way?

Comment: 1. There's often little point in replicating pointless Java stuff in Python. 2. You're sending the result of a function call, not the function itself, to `AbstractExample`. 3. Can you tell us exactly what result you're trying to accomplish rather than the Java weirdness you're trying to replicate to get that result?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 OK so generically I have this thing with sockets and I want to basically create an event if you will when something is received. I basically created a protocol for sending simple packets between server and client and people could use it as a library so I want them to be able to do something with a packet when it is received. (Ex: Scan the packet for specific data) so I want an event where the user/programmer has access to the packet that was received

Comment: In case you haven't read [this tutorial](http://pymotw.com/2/abc/) on abstract base classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python does not have abstract classes similar to Java. You can pass callables as values for function arguments.

```
class AbstractExample():

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def call_now_with_my_parameters(self, callable):
        callable(self.arg2, self.arg2)

def example_function(arg1,arg2):
    print("{},{}".format(arg1, arg2))

ae = AbstractExample(5, 7)
ae.call_now_with_my_parameters(example_function)
```

It seems to me you want is to store a callable and its arguments for later execution. Here with partial:

```
from functools import partial
p = partial(print, 'aef','qwe')
p()
em = partial(exampleMethod, 5, 6)
em()
```

You can then pass *p* and *em* variables around as function parameters.

May be this is what you intent to do:

```
from functools import partial


class AbstractExample():

    def __init__(self, callable):
        callable() # call it now

def example_function(arg1,arg2):
    print("{},{}".format(arg1, arg2))

call_this_later = partial(example_function)
// you can pass call_this_later as parameter
ae = AbstractExample(call_this_later(5, 7))
```

Comment: The main thing is that if you read my reply to TigerhawkT3s comment above, the arguments that go into the method I'm passing as an argument in my class are defined later in the code. basically, when I call the method in the init of the class (callable()) I want to pass the arguments then. I want to do callable(5,7) but that generates an error because Python requires that you already define the arguments when passing a method as an argument in a classes init method apparently. I'm wondering how I could get around this

Comment: Never mind the partial module totally solves my problem thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, to run `method`, you should use `method()`.

Also, you're executing `exampleMethod` before passing it to `AbstractExample`. You could do this, instead:

```
class AbstractExample():

    def __init__(self, method):
        method() #Run method

def exampleMethod(arg1,arg2):
    print str(arg1) + "," + str(arg2)

AbstractExample(lambda: exampleMethod(5,7))
```